# How to create server receiving streaming data through websocket?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, twilio-api, spring-websocket

I need to receive data that is sent by Twilio using MediaStreams. I tried to create handler, but connection never gets established - it's always 500 error code.

Stack trace:

```
2019-12-06 17:41:32.185 DEBUG 4099 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: org.springframework.web.socket.server.HandshakeFailureException: Uncaught failure for request http://xxxxx.ngrok.io/messages?encoding=text; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No 'javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer' ServletContext attribute. Are you running in a Servlet container that supports JSR-356?


2019-12-06 17:41:32.196 DEBUG 4099 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error?encoding=text", parameters={masked}
2019-12-06 17:41:32.199 DEBUG 4099 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2019-12-06 17:41:32.217 DEBUG 4099 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json, application/cbor]
2019-12-06 17:41:32.218 DEBUG 4099 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Fri Dec 06 17:41:32 MSK 2019, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, message=Uncaught f (truncated)...]
2019-12-06 17:41:32.237 DEBUG 4099 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 500
```

Websocket configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new SessionHandler(), "/messages").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

Session Handler:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class SessionHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    List<WebSocketSession> sessions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

     @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) {
        log.info("connection established");
        sessions.add(session);
    }
}
```

Comment: No `javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer` ServletContext attribute. Are you running in a Servlet container that supports JSR-356?

Comment: @Kayaman after I tried another approach: using ServerEndpoint and I got error code 404. Was referencing to this article: https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/23/spring-framework-4-0-m1-websocket-support